# Connecting to AdventureWorks database (SQL Server 2005 Express) through Visual Studio Professional 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I am following the ***learning* ASP.NET 3.5** by O'REILLY to write some ASP.NET 3.5 code using Visual Studio 2008 SP1.  I have gotten to the point to where I need to Configure a Data Source using the SqlDataSource control.  I chose **Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)** even though I have SQL Server Express 2005 - This seems like the only logical choice.

I get to the **Add Connection** window and successfully add a **Server name** and I use the **Select or enter a database name** of **AdventureWorks**.  When I click on Test Connection I get the **Test Connection Succeeded** message box.

Unfortunately, when I click OK I get an error message of the following:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKey Token=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependecies.  The system cannot find
the file specified.
```

At his point I am at a loss and everywhere I look and find something similar to my issue it involves other versions of either Visual Studio or SQL Server.

I'd really appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1):

You may investigate [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/es-ES/Offtopic/thread/70a5cb26-6b20-43a0-8cef-a0c5716a3e1c/) recipe.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reinstall your copy of SQL 2005 Express. But sure to install all of the client-side developer packages in the installer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.

Following the [suggestions in this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/es-ES/Offtopic/thread/70a5cb26-6b20-43a0-8cef-a0c5716a3e1c/) , I went to the "[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack, August 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en#filelist) " - and downloaded (and installed) the "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility Components ". This did not help.

Then I also downloaded and installed the following components: SharedManagementObjects.msi, sqlncli.msi, SQLSysClrTypes.msi.

And now it works for me.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express and Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition.